# "А потом нас дельфины снова себе забрали..." - можно? или к себе?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> А потом приплыла огромная белуха и стала дельфинов от нас отваживать –
>   сама хотела играть. И плескалась, и толкалась, очень хотела нас
>   катать, прямо уговаривала, но на ней никак не получалось – у неё
>   верхнего плавника нет. Только скорость наберет, с неё и
>   соскальзываешь. Зато натискались мы с нею от души. А потом нас
>   дельфины снова себе забрали…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**А потом нас дельфины снова к себе забрали…**

Забрать себе ― обычно присвоить, забрать к себе ― забрать в свою группу.

ЗАБРАТЬ,  2. кого-что. Взять откуда-л. (**с собой, к себе**). З. сына на прогулку. Забрал семью и увёз на дачу. 3. кого-что. Разг. **Присвоить,** отнять, захватить кого-, что-л.; взять насильно, против желания.